# Mexican Sinkhole Locations

Tags: data-request, geospatial, mexico

I'm looking for a dataset which catalogues the locations of all (or many) of the sinkholes in Mexico (specifically Yucatan), but I haven't had any luck.

I kind of hoped USGS would have some of the data.

Preferably, the data should be in CSV, XML or JSON format, but I can work with other formats.

Comment: What's an example of a sinkhole?

Comment: Have you contact their Mexican Geological there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are speaking of cenotes.

If so, a [shapefile of the locations of cenotes](http://bitacoraordenamiento.yucatan.gob.mx/documentos/detalles.php?IdArchivo=1058) is available from the [Territorial Ecological Planning Program of the State of Yucatan](http://bitacoraordenamiento.yucatan.gob.mx/galeria/index.php).